# HLT instruction causes General Protection Fault in QEMU

Tags: assembly, x86, qemu

I am running my protected mode kernel under QEMU, and it is causing a general protection fault when trying to execute the assembler HLT instruction. CPL is 0, IOPL is 0 in EFLAGS, interruptions are enabled.

Could this be a QEMU issue or am i missing something?

This happens when emulating SMP (Symmetric Multi-processor).

Comment: The same on non-SMP or with interrupts off (after a CLI). qemu-kvm-0.14.1.

Comment: true i have had an experience of that. Also it can happen if there is some problem with idt

Answer (score 1):

Check the DPL of Code Segment selector.

Answer (score 0):

It may not help, but we use asm ("hlt") all the time with qemu non smp and it works fine.

However calling it will likely lead to an interrupt having a chance to run. So are you sure the EIP is the asm hlt ? If so, you should objdump the .o to make sure the compiler generated what you think it did.

hth